# How to centre a text in xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, eclipse

How to make this paragraph aligned and centered ?

```
<dict>
  <key>value</key>
  <string>this is the text that i want to change and align </string>
</dict>
```

This is how it works:

[image]

This is what it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add some prints so we can have an idea of what you want? Aligned with what, centered where?

Comment: What paragraph? You have an XML Document which does not translate to anything.

Comment: Okay sir   this how it looks http://i.imgur.com/fFzOTdY.png  and this is how i want it to look http://i.imgur.com/KEHjTUX.png

Comment: How are you loading that XML... what language are you using?

Comment: @HichamEmpire Those look like the same image. How do you get from this XML to those images?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever method you are using to load the XML with and put it on the page, the containing element should be one that you style with CSS or inline styles to fit in the space you have designated, and adhere to the font, width, and centering rules you intend.